# Call a function in node.js programming

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```js
Manager.prototype.checkOrder = function() {
    var finish = function(err, filled) {
        if(!filled) {
            log.info(this.action, 'order was not (fully) filled, cancelling and creating new order');
            this.exchange.cancelOrder(this.order);
        }
        log.info(this.action, 'was successfull');
    }
    this.exchange.checkOrder(this.order, _.bind(finish, this));
}
```

And I don't know how to call it on other parts of the code.

I have tried this :

```
setTimeout(this.checkOrder, util.minToMs(1));
```

but it didn't work.
I want to do it without using setTimeout function.

Comment: how do you create ´exchange´ variable?

Comment: Your code for `checkOrder` method is incomplete, add full code

Comment: In node you can use module.exports to get this data on other parts.

Comment: I have reformatted your code to make it more readable. Remember, you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your questions to improve them as much as possible.

Comment: Do you understand what `Manager.prototype.checkOrder` means? It means you are placing this function on the prototype for objects created using `new Manager`. It makes no sense to even think about using it other than on instances of `Manager`--what would `this` be referring to otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using prototypes you probably want to create an Object first. After that you can call the method like every other function.

```
var myManager = new Manager();
myManager.checkOrder();
```

Comment: can I use this.checkOrder() directly ?

Comment: not really as you have side effects (this.action) in your method that require to have it bound to an object